# Can “cloven” be used instead of “cleaved”?

Tags: grammar, verbs, differences, adjectives, past-participles

Can *cloven* be used in its verb form like the way *broken* or *eaten* is used?

> gets cloven to give rise to
>
> is cloven by

*Cleaved* is a perfectly fine word in this context, but can *cloven* be used instead?

Comment: similar: [What is the difference between “proven” and “proved”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/what-is-the-difference-between-proven-and-proved)

Comment: To add to the confusion, how about 'cleft'?  As in, "cleft in twain", or "cleft chin".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloven is a less common past participle of the verb *to cleave*. It's actually used as an adjective, as in the expression "Cloven Hoof", but is not generally used as a past participle.