# Usage of Disproven

Tags: etymology, word-usage

How would you use disproven in a sentence please? Is disproven interchangeable with disproved?

Comment: *Disproven* is past participle, while *disproved* is past tense. As adjectives both work in the same way as any other vpt/vpp -- ***proven** technology*, not ***proved** technology*.

Comment: 'Using activity A is a disproven method of ___ ...' or 'Using activity A as a method of ___ was disproved by...'. As Kris mentions, disproven is an adjective to describe something that has been disproved, whereas disprove is the verb to prove something is false.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68380/is-proven-very-old-fashioned

Comment: The past participle of *prove* is either *proved* or *proven*. Both are used.

Comment: Also very much on point: [What is the difference between 'proven' and 'proved'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/what-is-the-difference-between-proven-and-proved/1609#1609)

Comment: @Kris The usual past participle is also _disproved_. And are you saying that _disproven technology_ sounds as natural as _proven technology_? I'm with [these Google Ngram findings](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proven+technology%2Cdisproven+technology&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproven%20technology%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @nickson104 There are virtually identical numbers of Google hits for "disproved theory" and "disproven theory". Though 'disproven is rarely used nowadays for the past participle.

Comment: Fair enough, I cant argue with the googly machine.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Please see my answer for comment on how *disproven technology* has little use at all.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proved+_NOUN_%2C+proven+_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproved%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproven%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Kris You seem to be missing the point that answering for 'proven / proved' is inappropriate here. And has already been done elsewhere.

Answer (score -3):

There are really two issues here.

The past participle as adjective (as in *a proven technology*) indicates a general condition. The past tense is also used as an adjective (a *proved technology*) in a specific case.

On the other hand, AmE has progressively been dropping/ deprecating the past participle, preferring the past tense for both the purposes. This is across verbs, not for *prove* alone, or for that matter, in case of adjective use alone.

Grammatically both are correct and acceptable. (Though I cannot imagine any practical use for *disproven* per se, though *proven* is very handy.) They have their uses as noted above. Both can be found in literature, with increasing use in AmE writing of the *pp* where the *pt* would be expected.

Comment: _Proved_ is an alternative to _proven_ as the past participle of _prove_. It is not normal in any variety of English I am aware of to use the past tense of verbs adjectivally (though of course in many verbs the past tense and the past participle are the same). There are a number of verbs where some dialects have a non-standard past participle (eg _writ_) sometimes of the same form as the past (eg _shook_, _broke_) but I don't think there's any evidence that this is a trend which is progressing.

Comment: "to use the past tense of verbs adjectivally (where the pp is distinct from pt)": There are uses for it. My answer has briefly dealt with the difference.

Comment: See also: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proved+_NOUN_%2C+proven+_NOUN_&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproved%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproven%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Your post has given no examples or references for the phenomenon you claim. I claim that your analysis is based on a mistake, viz that _proved_ is only past and not pp.

Comment: @ColinFine You could save so much effort if only you read my answer one more time at leisure. And (if so) avoid down voting on impulse.

Comment: I have read your answer a couple more times. It continues to say "The past tense is also used as an adjective (a proved technology) in a specific case." That is not the past tense: it is an alternative past participle.